# Jenkins Extensible Choice with user specific items based on users Roles

Tags: jenkins

I have a situation where I would like to alter the contents of a choice parameter in a Jenkins parametrised build.

In my case I would like one project for deploying the application 'Deploy My App'.  When building this project the user is presented with a choice parameter.  I would like to alter the contents of this list depending on a user role.  i.e. someone with the 'dev_deploy' role will be able to see the dev environments, someone with the 'test_deploy' role will be able to see the test environments etc.

I am currently using the Extensible Choice Parameter plugin and the Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin.

I know that I can write some groovey script to generate the list items for the choice.

```
def result = ["-------"]

def roles=??????

if(roles.get('dev_deploy') {
    //Add dev environments
    result.add('dev1')
    ....
}
if(roles.get('test_deploy') {
    //Add test environments
    result.add('test1')
    ....
}

return result
```

I just can't figure out who to get hold of the users roles?

Anyone know how I might do this, or have different solution to the problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, after a few more searches I came across the source (https://github.com/jenkinsci/role-strategy-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/com/michelin/cio/hudson/plugins/rolestrategy)

After further reading and a bit of playing around I came up with this...

```
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.*

def result = ["-- Please Select --"]
def authStrategy = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()

if(authStrategy instanceof RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy){
    def currentUser = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAuthentication().getName();
    def roleMap= authStrategy.roleMaps.get("globalRoles")

    def sids= roleMap.getSidsForRole("Manage_Dev")
    if(sids != null && sids.contains(currentUser)) {
        result.add("dev1")
        ...
    }

    sids= roleMap.getSidsForRole("Manage_Test")
    if(sids != null && sids.contains(currentUser)) {
        result.add("tst1")
        ...
    }
    ...
}

return result
```

Which works for me.  Easy when you know how!

Answer (score 1):

I came across code that helps me to overcome the same problem. I have refined the choice by using the Active Choice plugin and the Jenkins user role. Admins will have different drop-down options and a tester will have different drop-down options.

https://kinoshita.eti.br/2016/04/24/using-active-choices-with-role-strategy-plugin.html

```
import hudson.model.User
import hudson.model.Hudson
import hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy
import hudson.security.Permission
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleMap

AuthorizationStrategy strategy = Hudson.getInstance().getAuthorizationStrategy();

jobs = []
user = User.current()
userId = user.getId()

if (strategy != null && strategy instanceof com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy) {
    roleStrategy = (RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy) strategy;
    // not very straightforward to get the groups for a given user
    roles = roleStrategy.getGrantedRoles("globalRoles")
    for (entry in roles) {
        role = entry.key
        users = entry.value
        if (role.getName().equals("tester")) {
            if (userId in users) {
                jobs = ["PROJECT_FOR_TESTERS1", "PROJECT_FOR_TESTERS2"]
                break
            }
        } else if (role.getName().equals("admin")) {
            if (userId in users) {
                jobs = ["PROJECT_FOR_ADMINS1", "PROJECT_FOR_ADMINS2"]
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

return jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a slight adjustment to the accepted answer to get it to work.
See [Cannot invoke method getSidsForRole() on null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361187/cannot-invoke-method-getsidsforrole-on-null-object)

```
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.*

        def result = ['-- Please Select --']
        def authStrategy = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()

        if(authStrategy instanceof RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy){
        def currentUser = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAuthentication().getName();
        def roleMap = authStrategy.getRoleMap(com.synopsys.arc.jenkins.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleType.Global)

        def sids = roleMap.getSidsForRole("develop")
        if(sids != null && sids.contains(currentUser)) {
            result.add('staging')
        }

        sids = roleMap.getSidsForRole("admin")
        if(sids != null && sids.contains(currentUser)) {
            result.add('prod')
        }
      }

      return result
```