# Cannot invoke method getSidsForRole() on null object

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm breaking my head over this. I get error "Cannot invoke method getSidsForRole() on null object". I have

1. Plugin "Role-based Authorization Strategy" version 3.0
2. Have created Global Roles called "devops" & "developers". have given required access.
3. Added jenkins users to above roles.

When I run the pipeline with code below, I get the error above. Please help me what is missing ?

```
stage('Authorize')
        {
            steps{
                script{
                    if (currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause) != null)
                    {
                        println("Job is triggered by upstream build job, so need to authorize again. Let it run.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        def authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
                        if (authStrategy instanceof com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy)
                        {
                            def devops_users = authStrategy.roleMaps.globalRoles.getSidsForRole('devops')
                            def project_users = authStrategy.roleMaps.globalRoles.getSidsForRole('developers')
                            def user=currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()
                            def env=params.Environment

                            if(devops_users.contains(user) || (project_users.contains(user) && (env!='prod')))
                            {
                            println("Authorization successful! "+ user + " is authorised to run this pipeline");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            println(user + " is not authorised to run this pipeline in "+ env +" environment");
                            currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
                            error("Authorization failed!!! "+ user +" has insufficient privileges...")
                            }
                        }
                   else {
                        throw new Exception("RBAC plugin not found. Install it before using from plugin manager or contact DevOps Team")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Even a simple code below ran in "Script Console" returns null

```
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.*

def authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
def roleMap = authStrategy.roleMaps.get("globalRoles")
print authStrategy  // Print Correctly
print roleMap      // Prints Null
```

Answer (score 1):

Below syntax works for Plugin version 3.0

```
def role_maps = authStrategy.getRoleMap(com.synopsys.arc.jenkins.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleType.Global)
                            def devops_users = role_maps.getSidsForRole('devops')
                            def project_users = role_maps.getSidsForRole('developers')
                            def user=currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()
```